# NoClassDefFoundError HttpTransport in Eclipse using Google App Engine

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

I'm switching from the deprecated Files API to new Cloud Storage Client Library on an old project and seem to be having dependencies issues. I've failed to get Maven working so I am installing the required jars by hand. I can compile and run my servlet, but get this runtime error when I try to access Cloud SQL via DriverManager.getConnection():

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/http/HttpTransport
```

What jar is HttpTransport supposed to be in?

How can I check whether the war I upload to Google includes it?

I have all of these in my war/WEB-INF/lib and also in my Java Build Path Libraries:

```
From App Engine SDK:
    appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.25.jar
    appengine-api-labs.jar
    appengine-api.jar
    appengine-endpoints-deps.jar
    appengine-endpoints.jar
    appengine-jsr107cache-1.9.25.jar
    appengine-jsr107cache.jar
    datanucleus-appengine-1.0.10.final.jar
    datanucleus-core-1.1.5.jar
    datanucleus-jpa-1.1.5.jar
    geronimo-jpa_3.0_spec-1.1.1.jar
    geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
    jdo2-api-2.3-eb.jar
    jsr107cache-1.1.jar

The Cloud Storage Client Library:
    appengine-gcs-client-0.4.4.jar

Dependencies of the Cloud Storage Client Library:
    guava-18.0.jar
    joda-time-2.8.2.jar
    google-api-services-storage-v1beta2-rev77-1.20.0.jar

For good measure, every jar from the Cloud Storage API libs:
    commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
    google-api-client-1.20.0.jar
    google-api-client-1.20.0.jar.properties
    google-api-client-android-1.20.0.jar
    google-api-client-android-1.20.0.jar.properties
    google-api-client-appengine-1.20.0.jar
    google-api-client-gson-1.20.0.jar
    google-api-client-jackson2-1.20.0.jar
    google-api-client-java6-1.20.0.jar
    google-api-client-servlet-1.20.0.jar
    google-http-client-1.20.0.jar
    google-http-client-1.20.0.jar.properties
    google-http-client-android-1.20.0.jar
    google-http-client-android-1.20.0.jar.properties
    google-http-client-appengine-1.20.0.jar
    google-http-client-gson-1.20.0.jar
    google-http-client-gson-1.20.0.jar.properties
    google-http-client-jackson2-1.20.0.jar
    google-http-client-jackson2-1.20.0.jar.properties
    google-http-client-jdo-1.20.0.jar
    google-http-client-jdo-1.20.0.jar.properties
    google-oauth-client-1.20.0.jar
    google-oauth-client-1.20.0.jar.properties
    google-oauth-client-appengine-1.20.0.jar
    google-oauth-client-java6-1.20.0.jar
    google-oauth-client-jetty-1.20.0.jar
    google-oauth-client-servlet-1.20.0.jar
    gson-2.1.jar
    gson-2.1.jar.properties
    httpclient-4.0.1.jar
    httpcore-4.0.1.jar
    jackson-core-2.1.3.jar
    jackson-core-2.1.3.jar.properties
    jdo2-api-2.3-eb.jar
    jetty-6.1.26.jar
    jetty-util-6.1.26.jar
    jsr305-1.3.9.jar
    transaction-api-1.1.jar
```

Comment: Maybe this startup warning is a clue (note the two version numbers are identical): The API version in this SDK is no longer supported on the server!
-----------
Latest SDK:
Release: 1.9.25
Timestamp: Tue Jul 07 12:10:33 PDT 2015
API versions: [1]

-----------
Your SDK:
Release: 1.9.25
Timestamp: Thu Jul 23 12:07:39 PDT 2015
API versions: [1.0]

Comment: When the google plugin builds and uploads the war, it echoes the name of the temp directory it uses, so I could verify that the jars were indeed included. For me it was:

C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg312535284579766874.tmp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it had nothing to do with jar files, the classpath, or cloud storage. The app was using an old rdbms connection method for Cloud SQL that I didn't know had been deprecated:

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new AppEngineDriver());
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:google:rdbms://incredipede:instance/incredipede");
```

I gather the call to registerDriver was failing, so the required classes weren't available when I called getConnection(). Switching to the new mysql connection and Class.forName() method worked:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:google:mysql://incredipede:instance/incredipede?user=root");

Also must add this to appengine-web.xml:
<use-google-connector-j>true</use-google-connector-j>
```

Incidentally I noticed that entering the app engine instance name in eclipse (project > properties > google > app engine > google cloud sql > app engine sql instance) pops up similar HttpTransport errors even in a fresh project. This may be a bug in the appengine eclipse plugin or in appengine 1.9.25... I doubt these errors are intended behavior for the old connection method, deprecated or not.

Answer (score 0):

com/google/api/client/http/HttpTransport is a part of appengine-tools-api.jar

Comment: Adding appengine-tools-sdk-1.9.25.jar from mvnrepository.com didn't fix it. HttpTransport also appears to be in google-http-client, appengine-api, and appengine-endpoints, so I'm already including it 3 times. I guess this is a classpath issue.